# Understanding linux file system modes

Tags: permissions, filesystem, chmod

I've read through over 10 articles, and am trying to wrap my head around the linux file system. There is one point I am trying to get that I can't figure out. Forgive me for sounding very dumb:

When listing file details, I get a numeric "mode" of a file, which refers to its permissions. Some example modes:

```
33206
16822
```

Somehow, those seem to need to convert to octals, and look something like:

```
0777
```

From there, one can apparently deduce the human readable permissions, such as:

```
drwxr-xr-x
-rwxr--r--
```

I'm trying to figure out how get from this first step to the third. And I'm totally lost.

Comment: How exactly are you *"listing file details"*?

Answer (score 4):

The first set of numbers is probably nothing to do with the permission set for the file. If you got this information using `ls -l` then that number corresponds to the file size in bytes.

The octal values are not displayed in this format, but the 'human readable' is. The way that I remember octals is that the first of the four digits is to do with special bits (setuid, setgid, sticky) these are for more advanced usage, so I wouldn't worry about them straight away. Then each human readable set of rwx makes up the value of the next 3 digits, which are ordered by owner, group and everyone. r=4, w=2 and x=1, so read/write is 4+2=6.

The [Ubuntu help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions) is pretty clear I think.

I'd also suggest using `ls -lh` to list files, as the file size is converted to human readable, so it's output is in Kilobytes, Megabytes and Gigabytes.

Comment: I was using Node's `fs.stat` didn't want to get into the node part. So maybe that 'mode' thing is bS.

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3045

Comment: per isaac schleuter: `To see just the permissions in the standard octal format, you can do var permString = '0' + (stat.mode & 0777).toString(8)`

Comment: Aha!! Ok now I tested and in one example got 0755

Comment: I've never used node.js, but after having a look at those permissions I can see why you were confused!

Answer (score 4):

If you mean by "decimal notation" "octal notation": both octal and character notations are communicated between *nix users.

In particular notice that in permissions in octal and characters can be split in 3 parts. Like so:

```
rwx | r-x | r-x
7   | 5   | 5
```

Now look at the position of each letter.

- In first part, it is true, true, true (or set, set, set). What is number 7 in octal? 111.
- Second permission? set, unset, set. Octal 5? 101. As you can see octal notation in bits corresponds to the letters to set/unset.

As for the 3 sets, that's owner, that user's group, and other users and groups permissions. In the example above, owner can read write and execute, but users in owner's group and other users cannot write, they can only read and execute a file.

Comment: Thanks! See my comments below. I managed, in one case, to get `0755`. So do I just scratch the 0?

Comment: Might be useful : http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/103414/85039

Answer (score 2):

You can get the octals value with:

```
stat -c "%a %n" file
```

However there is a tons of file permissions calculator online:

- http://file-permissions.ninja
- http://permissions-calculator.org

and a lot more...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all of the help and hints of the other answers. I used these and a few other finds to piece together the following conversion solutions in JS:

```
converter = {

    listing: {
      '0': '---',
      '1': '--x',
      '2': '-w-',
      '3': '-wx',
      '4': 'r--',
      '5': 'r-x',
      '6': 'rw-',
      '7': 'rwx'
    },

    modeToRWX(mode) {
      let octal = this.modeToOctal(mode);
      let rwx = this.octalToRWX(octal);
      return rwx;
    },

    modeToOctal(mode) {
      let octal = '0' + (mode & 0o777).toString(8);
      return octal;
    },

    octalToRWX(octal) {
      if (!octal) { return void 0; }
      const list = this.listing;
      let full = String((octal.length === 4) ? octal : '0' + octal);
      let a = list[String(octal).charAt(1)];
      let b = list[String(octal).charAt(2)];
      let c = list[String(octal).charAt(3)];
      return a + b + c;
    }

}
```